# Error with CarrierWave , upload the old file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I use in my app Carrierwave for upload sounds.

But I have a bug, if I select a sound for upload but it's was the wrong sound like "toto.mp3", so I reselect an other sounds like "titi.mp3". When I upload now my sounds, The file in my app is the 1st sounds selected so is "toto.mp3" but I select "titi.mp3" not "toto.mp3".

I dont know how resolve this bug, if you can help.

Uploader

```
 # encoding: utf-8
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'

class SoundUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/files/#{model.user_id}/#{model.id}"
  end


  def extension_white_list
    %w(3ga 3gp 3g2 3gpp 3gp2 m4a m4b m4p m4v m4r mp4 aac flac flv avi asf wma wmv dpx mkv mka mks bwf mpg mpeg mp1 mp2 mp3 
      m1v m1a m2a mpa mpv rm mov ogm ogg ogv oga ogx nut riff webm weba wav mxf asx ts aiff aif aifc au snd caf)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
    model.title = original_filename if model.title.to_s ==  ''
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
  end
end
```

And my Javascript :

```
$(function () {
    $('#new_sound').fileupload({
        dataType: 'script',
        dropZone: $('#new_sound'),
        acceptFileTypes:  /(3ga|3gp|3g2|3gpp|3gp2|m4a|m4b|m4p|m4v|m4r|mp4|aac|flac|flv|avi|asf|wma|wmv|dpx|mkv|mka|mks|bwf|mpg|mpeg|mp1|mp2|mp3|m1v|m1a|m2a|mpa|mpv|rm|mov|ogm|ogg|ogv|oga|ogx|nut|riff|webm|weba|wav|mxf|asx|ts|aiff|aif|aifc|au|snd|caf)$/i,
        limitMultiFileUploads: 1,
        add: function (e, data){
            var file = data.files[0];
            var filetype = $(this).fileupload('option', 'acceptFileTypes');
            if (filetype.test(file.name)) {
                $('#title').val(file.name);
                $('#select_file').css('color', '#00A300');
                $('#send_file').css('display', 'inline');
                $("#send_file").on('click', function () { data.submit(); });
                $("#stop_file").on('click', function () {
                    $('#progress_file .bar').css('width', '0%');
                    data.abort();
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Format de fichier non supporté.');
            }
        },
        progress: function (e, data){
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress_file .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: I think i see where is the mistake, the mistake is in my javascript.
I give you my uploader and my javascript

Comment: I find the bug , and i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the bug , just in JS I delete the line : limitMultiFileUploads: 1, and now that work. :)

**Before**

```
$('#new_sound').fileupload({
        dataType: 'script',
        dropZone: $('#new_sound'),
        acceptFileTypes:  /(3ga|3gp|3g2|3gpp|3gp2|m4a|m4b|m4p|m4v|m4r|mp4|aac|flac|flv|avi|asf|wma|wmv|dpx|mkv|mka|mks|bwf|mpg|mpeg|mp1|mp2|mp3|m1v|m1a|m2a|mpa|mpv|rm|mov|ogm|ogg|ogv|oga|ogx|nut|riff|webm|weba|wav|mxf|asx|ts|aiff|aif|aifc|au|snd|caf)$/i,
        limitMultiFileUploads: 1,
```

**After**

```
$('#new_sound').fileupload({
        dataType: 'script',
        dropZone: $('#new_sound'),
        acceptFileTypes:  /(3ga|3gp|3g2|3gpp|3gp2|m4a|m4b|m4p|m4v|m4r|mp4|aac|flac|flv|avi|asf|wma|wmv|dpx|mkv|mka|mks|bwf|mpg|mpeg|mp1|mp2|mp3|m1v|m1a|m2a|mpa|mpv|rm|mov|ogm|ogg|ogv|oga|ogx|nut|riff|webm|weba|wav|mxf|asx|ts|aiff|aif|aifc|au|snd|caf)$/i,
```